# How to set minimum value of the text box based on the combobox value in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried a writing the code to set the limit of the textbox means if somebody enters the value 8 and if the limit in the code is set to the 10 then it should give message that pl. increase the entered value but adding to this its value of the limit also gets changed as per the value getting changed in the combo box means i have list of 5 to 7 numbers and there respective list if somebody selects the specific limit then the program should consider that adjacent cell value as respectively as shown in the image

For Eg: If someone selects the number 4456 then the minimum value of entering in the textbox is more than 50 same as if someone selects the 5566 number then minimum value entering in the textbox is more than 150 respectively if someone enters the value below that then it should show message that pl. increase the value with showing that minimum value requirement is 50 for 4456 eg.

Pl. help in getting solution of this
Any positive response are welcomed.
Pl. find the images of the userform and the sheet layout containing value in the attached document.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim t As Long, LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For t = 2 To LastRow
If Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = ws.Cells(t, "H").Value Then
Me.TextBox1 = ws.Cells(t, "I").Value

If Val(Me.ComboBox1.Value) = ws.Cells(t, "H").Value Then
If Val(Me.TextBox2.Value) < ws.Cells(t, "J").Value Then
    MsgBox ("Has to be greater than")
    
    End If
    End If

  End If

 Next t

 End Sub
```

[User form Image the limit of value should be given to second textbox][1]
[Limits value ][2]

Regards,
Shubham Mehta

Comment: I cannot understand anything from your question. Maybe I am tired... Which to be the logic based on what the limitation to be set?

Comment: Which TextBox is entered by the user? TextBox1 or TextBox2? I see the code loops though a column and puts values into TextBox1, is this the one that has to be above a minimum value?

Comment: @FaneDuru there is one combo box in which there will be numbers like 4450 and all in the last text box if somebody enters the value like 8 then message should be given that the value in that text box should be more than 50 this is the one limit while the value of the limit is getting changed like for 5566 the limit is 150 so if somebody has selected 5566 in the combo box and entered the value in the text box then for that the minimum value has to 150

Comment: Value in the Textbox2 is entered by the user @Toddleson

Comment: You did not clarify anything trying to answer my question, I am afraid...  Which to be the connection between 4450 and its minimum (50)? The same for 5566 (min 151) and so on. You should set such conditions for each value in the combo box. Or create another column in the combo to keep this corresponding minimum, or an array, or something. Then, dealing with it in the event should be easy. In your code I can only see comparisons with range values. Are the limits in column J:J? If yes, how to interpret them according to the combo value?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best form here is to create a function which can save and return all of those number combinations. Like so:

```vb
Function CurrentMinimumValue() As Long
'Manually type in all the pairs of selected numbers and the corresponding minimum values
    Select Case Me.ComboBox1.Value
        Case 10
            CurrentMinimumValue = 5
        Case 20
            CurrentMinimumValue = 15
        Case 4456
            CurrentMinimumValue = 50
        Case 5566
            CurrentMinimumValue = 150
    End Select
End Function
```

Which can be used like:

```vb
Sub test()
    Me.Combobox1.Value = 4456
    MsgBox "The current minimum value allowed is " & CurrentMinimumValue()
    MsgBox "Is the entered value above the minimum? " & Me.TextBox2.Value > CurrentMinimumValue()
End Sub
```

The line you were asking about can be rewritten like:

```vb
If Val(Me.TextBox2.Value) < CurrentMinimumValue() Then
    MsgBox  "Has to be greater than " & CurrentMinimumValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your example, assume the textbox is named `TextBox2`, then the following code allows you to check the value entered and issue a message:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_AfterUpdate()

    If Me.Value < ComboBox1.Value Then
        MsgBox "Value must be larger than " & ComboBox1.Value
        Button_OK.Enabled = False
    Else
        Button_OK.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You must place this function in the code section of your user form.